# Procedimiento para dar permisos a un usuario en Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-11g, stored-procedure

Estoy tratando de crear un procedimiento que recibe como parámetro el usuario al que desean otorgarle los permisos de tablas directamente. Sé que sería mejor con un rol y simplemente otorgarlo, pero es un ejercicio, crear un procedimiento que permita darle permisos a X usuario sobre tablas.

Hice este código pero me aparece un error en el `GRANT CREATE` y me sale subrayada la palabra `create` (uso `ORACLE SQL Developer`), si lo borro (esta sentencia), aparece subrayada la siguiente sentencia (lo que coloqué después del `GRANT`), en este caso, al borrar todo el `GRANT create table TO usuario;` se subraya el `update` de la siguiente sentencia.

El código es el siguiente

```
create or replace PROCEDURE Gran_toAnyTables (usuario varchar2) AS
BEGIN
  GRANT create table TO usuario;
  GRANT update any table TO usuario;
  GRANT insert any table TO usuario;
  GRANT select any table TO usuario;
  GRANT delete any table TO usuario;
  GRANT COMMENT ANY TABLE TO usuario;
  GRANT BACKUP ANY TABLE TO usuario;
END Gran_toAnyTables;
```

Y el error que me aparece al compilarlo es el siguiente

> "PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "GRANT" when expecting one of the
> following:
>
> ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma    raise
> return select update while with       <<    continue close current
> delete fetch lock insert open rollback    savepoint set sql execute
> commit forall merge pipe purge "

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En un procedimiento, solo puedes ejecutar de forma estática sentencias *DML*, como `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`.

En contraste, no puedes ejecutar de la misma manera sentencias *DDL*, como `GRANT`, `CREATE`, `ALTER`, `DROP`, etc...  Para poder ejecutar este tipo de sentencia, debes hacerlo usando SQL dinámico con la ayuda de `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.

En tu caso, el equivalente usando `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` sería lo siguiente:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE Gran_toAnyTables (usuario varchar2) AS
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT create table TO ' || usuario;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT update any table TO ' || usuario;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT insert any table TO ' || usuario;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT select any table TO ' || usuario;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT delete any table TO ' || usuario;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT COMMENT ANY TABLE TO ' || usuario;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT BACKUP ANY TABLE TO ' || usuario;
END Gran_toAnyTables;
```

---

Por si acaso, deseo avisarte, que aunque lo que te menciono es correcto, existen otras sutilidades con el uso de procedimientos que te pudieran tomar por sorpresa y causar problemas de acceso dependiendo del usuario que empleas para definir y ejecutar el procedimiento. Te dejo el enlace siguiente por si acaso te topas con esos problemas después de resolver el problema descrito en tu pregunta: [I have a PL/SQL procedure which won't work because of 'insufficient privileges', but it works in SQL*Plus it all seems to work. Why ?](http://www.jlcomp.demon.co.uk/faq/plsql_privs.html).

Comment: Muchas gracias, es justo lo que necesitaba